# is it possible to list directory even though you put index.html in there?

Tags: httpd

is it possible to list all files in directory ?

asdf.com/dir/

but dir has index.html in it, so when you navigate to it index.html pops up.

for precaution i have added

```
        IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: So, do you want to show the listing despite existing index.html or prevent it from showing anyhow?

Comment: i want to prevent users being able ot view the directory listings. i have put index.html. for extra precaution i put indexignore * to hide all files in directory.

Answer (score 1):

Misunderstood your question -- the way I read it, it seemed that you wanted to *list* all the files in the directory. I've edited my answer below.

You need something like this in `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/foo/dir">
    AllowOverride Indexes
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Attempting to list the contents of that directory will always result in 403 Forbidden.

Alternatively, you can put a blank index.html in there, and it will have the same effect. Users will not be able to view the directory listing. `IndexIgnore` is not explicitly needed.

Comment: does indexignore * not work ?

Comment: Misunderstood your question (I thought you wanted the reverse). See my edited answer above.